# If the sequence $s_{n}$ converges to $l$, does $\frac{1}{s_{n}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{l}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not sure if that's true, in our textbook there is only an affirmation that if $s_{n}$ converges to $l$ then $\frac{1}{s_{n}}$ is bounded, but I think that it also should converge to $\frac{1}{l}$ (when $l \neq 0$ obviously). I tried to prove it by definition of convergence but didn't get anywhere. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you use
$$\left|\frac1{s_n}-\frac1\ell\right|=\left|\frac{\ell-s_n}{\ell s_n}\right|?$$ To make progress on the right hand side a simple way is to derive a strictly positive lower bound for $|s_n|$, valid for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$l \ne 0, \tag 1$

there is an open set $N$ containing $l$ with

$0 \notin N; \tag 2$

then the function

$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} \tag 3$

is continuous on $N$; thus if

$s_n \to l \tag 4$

we have

$\dfrac{1}{s_n} = f(s_n) \to f(l) = \dfrac{1}{l}. \tag 5$